# Modify FileStream

Tags: c#, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm working now on a class that will allow editing very big text files (4Gb+). Well it may sound a little stupid but I do not understand how I can modify text in a stream. 
Here is my code:

```
public long  Replace(String text1, String text2)
{
    long replaceCount = 0;
    currentFileStream = File.Open(CurrentFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);

    using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(currentFileStream))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))  
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(text1))
            {
                line.Replace(text1, text2);

                // Here I should save changed line
                replaceCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return replaceCount;
}
```

Comment: sorry mixed up your sample (that does not write anything at all) with Ehsan Ullah' one (which is using `StringBuilder` which is clearly not going to help you with large files). Deleting my answer.

Comment: This just can't work in the general case.  Only in the very unusual case when the replacement is exactly as long as the original.  Files don't permit inserts and deletions in the middle of the file.  So a completely rewrite of the file is required.  If you've got 4 jiggabyte text files then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant, the 4GB+ files are not the result of the operation, but I've processing existing large files...

Answer (score 1):

You are not replacing it anywhere in your code. You should save all the text and then write it again to the file. Like,

```
  public long  Replace(String text1, String text2)
 {
  long replaceCount = 0;
   currentFileStream = File.Open(CurrentFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(currentFileStream))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))  
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string textToAdd = line;
        if (line.Contains(text1))
        {
            textToAdd = line.Replace(text1, text2);

            // Here I should save changed line
            replaceCount++;
        }
        sb.Append(textToAdd);
    }
}
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename , fileMode, fileAccess))
        {
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
            streamWriter.Write(sb.ToString());
            streamWriter.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
        }
return replaceCount;
```

}

Comment: It is not possible to save all text, there is no space for additional files on the disk, so I just want to find how I can replace changed line in bs Stream

Comment: You can delete the old file before writing the new one.

Comment: @SergiuCojocaru I don't think it is possible to read and write in the same go. You have to read and then write.

Comment: Well I thought same, but posted here, may be someone has a solution without creating temp files.

Comment: There's nothing especially unusual about multi-gigabyte text files. Grab the Wikipedia download sometime, for example. Or some meteorological data from the NOAA, or survey data, or a Web crawler log, or . . .